# Core Plot - Drawing only the points in a specific range of the graph

Tags: core-plot

I have a simple scatter plot with ~500,000 points on it.  Having this many points on the graph really makes my app lag, which isn't surprising.  I was wondering if there was a way to only draw the points for a specific x range (like 0-100 or 500-1000).  The user will only be looking at certain points of the graph (via zooming in), so it would make it much less laggy if the program only had to plot a small amount of those points.

I've tried having the graph re-draw itself, every time the user zooms in/out or moves the axis, but this actually seems to make the app run slower.  Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to filter the data and only provide the visible points to the plot in your datasource. Use a plot space delegate to detect when the visible area changes and adjust the data as needed. The best way to do this will depend on how your app stores its data internally. You'll want to use a data structure that lets you quickly determine which points need to be plotted.

You don't want to reload all of the data every time something changes. The plots have methods to insert and remove ranges of data points while preserving the rest of the data. If you're only changing a few points at a time, this is much faster than reloading all of the data every time. The "Real-Time Plot" demo in the Plot Gallery app shows one way to use these methods.